# django-image-kit Changing Processor Values Inside Admin Save

Tags: django, image-resizing, django-imagekit

I am trying to use image-kit with admin image uploads. In my edit form there are fields for width and height. I need a way to pass these values to image-kit's processors.

But i can not find a way... ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :
Imagekit version is development version (2, 0, 0, 'alpha', 1)
Suppose we are in image model admin.py

---

#### this function will be used as callable, instance is the image object

def getThumb(file, instance):
    return [resize.ResizeToFill(width=instance.width, height=instance.height)]

class Image(Media):
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

```
file = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/uploads/images/bigs')  
### IMAGE-KIT we are passing a callable function as processors to ImageSpecField 
thumbnail = ImageSpecField( processors = getThumb, image_field='file', format='JPEG', options={'quality': 90}) 

### override admin save function
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):       
    # Call the "real" save() method in the base class 'models.Model'        
    super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 
    test = Image.objects.all()[0]  
    test.thumbnail.width ### getting a property means completing upload of imagekit file
```